# Setting up listener using web3py

Tags: erc-20, events, etherscan, web3.py

I'm setting up a proof of work contract. When a solution is found, the contract emits a Transfer event and the number that gets hashed with future solutions changes. I need to set up a listener so that the miner knows when this number has updated.

I've written my contract in web3py so far, so help going about this in web3py would be awesome.